# How can I kill an express process when is running in a port

Tags: node.js, express, service, electron

I am using the module express on my Electron project and when i try to close this service

```
        expreso.get('/test', function(req, res, next){    
            res.json({"key": "value"});   
            newWin.reload();
        })
```

is still working in the same port...

`express.close()` didn't work, neither the module https://github.com/moebius-mlm/http-graceful-shutdown and https://www.npmjs.com/package/kill-port

```
        service = new BrowserWindow({
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true,
                alwaysOnTop: false,
            },
            show: false,
            frame: false,
            skipTaskbar: true,
        })
        service.once('ready-to-show', () => {
            service.show()
          })
        service.setMenu(null)
        service.setSize(600, 400)
        service.setPosition(0, 0)
        service.loadURL("http://192.168.6.58:9001/genius/logout")
        service.close()

        newWin.close()
        newWin = new BrowserWindow({
            webPreferences: {
                nodeIntegration: true,
                alwaysOnTop: true,
                skipTaskbar: true,
            },
            show: false,
            frame: false,
        })
        newWin.show()
        newWin.setMenu(null)
        newWin.setSize(600, 400)
        newWin.setPosition(0, 0)
        newWin.loadURL("http://192.168.6.58:5000/logout/192.168.4.216")
        setTimeout(function(){ newWin.close(); }, 5000)
        server.close();
```

the `server.close()` at the end don't work as i supposed.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZ5Pz.png

Answer (score -1):

You're a Windows user. Enter the command to find the process that is running as shown below:

```sh
ps
```

Then you'll see something like this:

```sh
PID   PPID  PGID  WINPID TTY   UID    STIME    COMMAND
8468  29784 8468  29576  cons1 197609 21:43:58 /usr/bin/ps
29784 1     29784 29784  cons1 197609 16:12:58 /usr/bin/bash 
11220 26724 26724 35960  cons0 197609 16:13:41 /c/Program Files/nodejs/node 
26724 9976  26724 31940  cons0 197609 16:13:41 /usr/bin/sh
9976  1     9976  9976   cons0 197609 09:14:22 /usr/bin/bash
```

Do you see that the `PID 'of the node is 11220? Again, enter the command in the shell:

```sh
kill -9 11220
```

Then type the command `ps` and it looks like this:

```sh
PID   PPID  PGID  WINPID TTY   UID    STIME    COMMAND
8468  29784 8468  29576  cons1 197609 21:43:58 /usr/bin/ps
29784 1     29784 29784  cons1 197609 16:12:58 /usr/bin/bash 
26724 9976  26724 31940  cons0 197609 16:13:41 /usr/bin/sh
9976  1     9976  9976   cons0 197609 09:14:22 /usr/bin/bash
```

If you followed the above command, you should now be able to run the server again on port 3000.